# Reduced degrees of polynomials over a finite field

Tags: polynomials, field-theory, finite-fields

Theorems for polynomials over infinite fields are often modified for a finite field $\mathbb{F}_q$ by reducing the exponents of each monomial in the polynomial so that they are of the form $X^k$ where $k \leq q-1$ (because $X^{q-1} = 1$.) Is it true that the reduced polynomials must divide the original polynomial? It is true, for instance, in the case of $X^q + 1 = (X + 1)^q$ whose reduced form is $X + 1$, but I can’t seem to think of any counterexamples.

I imagine this can be easily proven or disproven, but I can’t seem to do so.

Comment: $X^{q-1}$ is not $1$: it’s $1$ if $X \in \mathbb{F}_q$ is nonzero, but $0$ otherwise. Perhaps you meant $X^q=X$? But if so, consider $X^4+1$ in $\mathbb{F}_3$.

Comment: @Aphelli Right, I forgot to add that condition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$X^2+1$ doesn't divide $X^4+1$ in $\Bbb{F}_3[X]$.